# Read a double * in Swift

Tags: swift

I have an Obj-C method that returns a `double *`, how is this accessed in Swift as a `Double`?

I get this error

```
Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>' to expected argument type 'Double'
```

I am calling this `- (double * _Nonnull) modIntensityForDestination:(int) destination;`

and failing when I do this

`let intensity = audioEngine.modIntensityForDestination(Int32(modDestinationID))`

I have tried `withUnsafeMutablePointer` but cant seem to get it working.

Comment: Please show your Objective-C function header, and the Swift code causing that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method returns a pointer to a *single* floating point number
then you can dereference it with `.memory`:

```
let intensity = audioEngine.modIntensityForDestination(...).memory
```

In Swift 3 it would be `.pointee`.